# Fastest way to remove hyphens from a string

Tags: javascript

I have IDs that look like: **185-51-671** but they can also have letters at the end, **175-1-7b**

All I want to do is remove the hyphens, as a pre-processing step.  Show me some cool ways to do this in javascript?  I figure there are probably quite a few questions like this one, but I'm interested to see what optimizations people will come up with for "just hyphens"

Thanks!

edit: I am using jQuery, so I guess .replace(a,b) does the trick (replacing a with b)

```
numberNoHyphens = number.replace("-","");
```

any other alternatives?

edit #2:

So, just in case anyone is wondering, the correct answer was

```
numberNoHyphens = number.replace(/-/g,"");
```

and you need the "g" which is the pattern switch or "global flag" because

```
numberNoHyphens = number.replace(/-/,"");
```

will only match and replace the first hyphen

Comment: You don't need to annotate the title of your question with [solved] - this is implied by giving the 'green check' to the answer that solved your problem.  Questions with accepted answers are visually distinct on StackOverflow from questions without an accepted answer.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You need to include [the global flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
var str="185-51-671";
var newStr = str.replace(/-/g, "");
```

Comment: Is there a way of just trimming the hyphens at the start of the string and leaving the ones in the middle of the string?  so '--this-is-a-string' would become 'this-is-a-string'

Comment: @abyrne85, yes, there is a way, however, it would be best if you asked a new question.

Comment: this gives me an error in my IDE: `expected expression, found \`/\``

Comment: To remove the hyphens from the beginning of the string: `var str = '--- te - st end -'; str = str.replace(/^-+/g, '');`. Then .trim() to remove whitespaces too. Or use this regex: `str = str.replace(/^(-|\s+)+/g, '');`

Comment: @Avatar neither of the examples that you provided work as the OP requested. I suggest instead of creating a new answer in the comments that you should actually create a new answer...then we can downvote it :-)

Answer (score 14):

This is *not* faster, but

```
str.split('-').join('');
```

should also work.

I set up a jsperf test if anyone wants to add and compare their methods, but it's unlikely anything will be faster than the `replace` method.

http://jsperf.com/remove-hyphens-from-string

Answer (score 8):

```
var str='185-51-671';
str=str.replace(/-/g,'');
```

Comment: ...and it seems like both of you (you and CrisDeBlonde) answered this one at the exact same instant haha

Answer (score 8):

Gets much easier in [`String.prototype.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll). Check out the browser support for the [built-in method](https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceAll).

```js
const str = '185-51-671';
console.log(str.replaceAll('-', ''));
```

Comment: What's up my 2021 people!  This has lots of modern support and has high readability.  str.replaceAll should be the accepted answer as of now, as long as you don't need to cover one off or unsupported browsers. (RIP Internet Explorer.)

In case you are learning it, if you need a space to replace what you are removing, simply add a space to the 2nd argument: str.replaceAll("removeditem", " ");

Answer (score 0):

Som of these answers, prior to edits, did not remove all of the hyphens.  You would need to use `.replaceAll("-","")`

Comment: There is no `replaceAll()` method defined on the String object or its prototype. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: @RobJohansen it's been a decade. but I think it's now in every browser  but IE. took about long enough. am I reading the browser chart correctly?

Answer (score -4):

In tidyverse, there are multiple functions that could suit your needs. Specifically, I would use `str_remove`, which will replace in a string, the giver character by an empty string (""), effectively removing it ([check here the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_remove)). Example of its usage:

```
str_remove(x, '-')
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why do you answer a 10-year-old JavaScript question that has nothing to do with the R programming language with a solution in tidyverse?

Comment: In addition to this being in the wrong language, R doesn't differentiate between single and double quotes. Either one would work *in R*